# Golf app getting average score by golf course and teebox

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

As you can see, I have 30 golf scorecards. 3 scorecards from course 1 and 27 scorecards from course 2.

I need a function/method that can calculate the average score for s1,s2,s3…s18, separated by courseID and teeID.

scorecards

```
[
    {courseID: 1,  teeID: 1   , s1: 4,   s2: 3,   s3: 5,   …s18: 4},
    {courseID: 1,  teeID: 1   , s1: 4,   s2: 3,   s3: 5,   …s18: 4},
    {courseID: 1,  teeID: 1   , s1: 4,   s2: 3,   s3: 5,   …s18: 4},
…3 scorecards
],

[
    {courseID: 2,  teeID: 1   , s1: 4,   s2: 3,   s3: 5,   …s18: 4},
    {courseID: 2,  teeID: 1   , s1: 4,   s2: 3,   s3: 5,   …s18: 4},
    {courseID: 2,  teeID: 1   , s1: 4,   s2: 3,   s3: 5,   …s18: 4},
…27 scorecards
];
```

Comment: I don't know golf but could you explain the course, tee played and hole?

Comment: I edited my initial question, hopefully it will help you understand what I’m trying to do. I’m a rookie at dart.